# String concatenation C++

Tags: c++, concatenation

Given an arbitrary floating point number, say `-0.13`, suppose we have an algorithm which calculates a binary string of known length `L` for this number, one by one, from left to right.

(I need to do this computation for calculating the Morton Key ordering for particles(co-orindates given) which in turn in used in building octrees. I am creating 
such binary strings for each of x,y,z dimensions)

Is it better/efficient to first create a character array of length `L`, and then convert this array into a string? i.e.

```
char ch[L];

for(i = 0; i < L; ++i)
{
    // calculation of ch[i]
}

//convert array into string
```

Or is it better/efficient to start of with a empty string, and then concatenate a new calculated bit into the string on the fly. i.e.

```
string s = "";

for(i = 0; i < L; ++i)
{
    // calculation of ch[i]
    s = s + string(ch);
}
```

Comment: You could hack it and read out the bit pattern of the IEEE float binary representation :-)

Comment: Generally it's more efficient to place characters into an existing character array rather than concatenating a character to a string. But why are you worried about this? Unless you're doing it billions of times it's unlikely to make a difference. Use the code that's clearest.

Comment: Your second code sample is unclear; I've edited it. Is this what you meant to say?

Comment: yes i meant to say that. wrote the question in a rush. Sorry about that and thanks for the edit!

Comment: It should be noted that your first one does not create a valid, null-terminated `char*`. It is simply an array of `char`s. If you pass that to any function expecting a null-terminated `char*`, you will get unpleasant results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not do both?

```
std::string myStr(L);

for(i = 0; i < L; ++i)
{
    // calculation of ch[i]
    myStr[i] = ch;
}
```

This creates a `std::string` with a given size. You then just set each character. This will *only* work if you can know the size beforehand exactly.

Alternatively, if you want something that is safe, even if you have to add more than `L` characters:

```
std::string myStr;
myStr.reserve(L);

for(i = 0; i < L; ++i)
{
    // calculation of ch[i]
    myStr.push_back(ch);
}
```

`std::string::reserve` preallocates the storage, but `push_back` will allocate more if needs be. If you don't go past `L` characters, then you will only get the one initial allocation.

Comment: `push_back` incurs a performance penalty; it has to check whether to grow the internal array.

Comment: @Oli: And it is also 100% impervious to buffer overruns. I'll take that tradeoff any day of the week.

Comment: The question was specifically about "efficiency", no matter how misguided that might be.

Answer (score 2):

Use the latter, but also call `s.reserve(L)` before entering the loop. This is almost as efficient as direct array assignment, but still easier to grok.

**EDIT:** Other answers suggest using `push_back()`. Vote for them.

> Sidebar: I'm not sure what you are computing, but if you just want to generate a string representation of the number, I'd suggest you simply call `sprintf()`, or insert the number into a `std::stringstream`.

Comment: He he thanks for pointing that out! I wrote that question in a bit if a hurry! But someone has thankfully corrected my sin :-)

Comment: Doing this computation for calculating the Morton Keys used in building octrees. See edit

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I fully understand the conversion happening, but we have objects for a reason.  If you use `std::string::reserve()` first, the performance should be minuscule, and it's obvious what the intent is.

```
string s;
s.reserve(L);
for(i = 0; i < L; ++i)
{
    // calculation of ch[i]
    string.push_back(ch);
}
```

If speed is absolutely necessary, you can instead initialize the string as length L, and bypass length checks:

```
string s(L,'\0');
for(i = 0; i < L; ++i)
{
    // calculation of ch[i]
    string[i] = ch;
}
```

Comment: `push_back` incurs a performance penalty; it has to check whether to grow the internal array.

Comment: @Oli: I don't know how smart compilers are these days, but a data flow analysis after inlining should reveal that the test is redundant.

Comment: I left it there since it also incurs exceptions if you do it wrong, helping to prevent run-time errors.  The faster method is not guaranteed to throw an exception.

Answer (score 2):

Can't you just use a string with a pre-allocated length?

```
string s(L, '\0');
for(i = 0; i < L; ++i)
{
    // calculation of ch[i]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Personally, i am probably out of date, but i use

sprintf ( char * str, const char * format, ... );

to create strings from numbers

sprintf ( outString,"%f", floatingPointNumber);

Comment: It's unclear if the OP is actually converting to base 10 or not.  He just says "calculates a binary string of known length".

Comment: no i am not converting to base 10. I need the binary string only.

Comment: With the sprintf method, you end up with a binary string in an array, as the char *  points to an array of chars.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the C++ way, use [`ostringstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostringstream/).  This is generally cleaner code, less error-prone, and easier to read:

```
float f = ... // whatever you set it to
std::ostringstream s;
s << f;
std::string stringifiedfloat = s.str();
// now you have the float in a string.
```

Alternately, you can use the C way, [`sprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sprintf/).  This is generally more error-prone, and harder to read, but faster performance:

```
float f = ... // whatever you set it to
char* buffer = new char[L];
sprintf(buffer, "%f", f);
// now you have the float in a string.
```

Or, you could even use boost's [`lexical_cast`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/conversion/lexical_cast.htm).  This has better performance than ostringstream, and better readability than sprintf, but it gives you a dependency on boost:

```
float f = ... // whatever you set it to
std::string stringified = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(f);
// now you have the float in a string.
```